# Роутинги с одинаковой формой адреса Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть список задач по адресу /tasks. Отображаются все.
При вводе /tasks/{taskId} должна отображаться одна конкретная задача. Это есть
Но также есть роут /tasks/{slug}, когда должны отображаться все задачи заданной категории.
Прописал маршруты:

`Route::get('/tasks/{slug}', [TaskController::class, 'showByCategory'])->name('tasks.showByCategory'); Route::get('/tasks/{task}', [TaskController::class, 'show'])->name('tasks.show');`

Вот связи в моделях:
Task:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

Category:

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}
```

Вот сам контроллер:

```
public function showByCategory(string $slug)
{
    $tasks = $this->taskService->showByCategory('red');

    $data = new TaskResource($tasks);

    try {
        return view('tasks_by_slug', ['data' => $data]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Failed to show your tasks: ' . $e]);
    }
}
```

При переходе по айди работает роутинг, но при попытке перейти по адресу slug бьёт 404. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: У вас пути одинаковые, и методы (GET) тоже одинаковые. Идет перезапись при их объявлении в routes.php, поэтому и работает только один роут.

Comment: Видимо вот это https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::get('/tasks/{task}', [TaskController::class, 'show'])->name('tasks.show');
Route::get('/tasks/{slug}/edit', [TaskController::class, 'showByCategory'])->name('tasks.showByCategory');
```

Поскольку у вас 2 роута с типом GET на одном уровне, то можно сказать, что Laravel "обьединяет"их, то есть не может увидеть различия.

Если простой вариант то добавьте к slug /edit ,как я написал выше - это поможет.

Comment: Спасибо, а ради интереса, какой вариант "посложнее"?

Comment: сделать прослойку которая будет перехватывать аргумент и вызывать нужную модель. по типу как сделано в модуле sluggble